My Turtle Crossing Game on Python : Collision function does not work
I've been trying the Turtle crossing game. It's basically getting the Turtle start out at the bottom of the screen and have it move across the screen while several randomly generated cars travel from the left to the right. The goal is to have your turtle cross the screen avoiding the cars.
While remaining parts of the code is okay, I'm having trouble with detecting collission with cars. I've shared the code relating to just the collision function below. And I'm following a course where the instructor did exactly this and got it to work. Is there anything wrong with my code?
Tried matching the position of car and player via .pos - nothing seems to work. It sometimes works, sometimes just lets the car zoom past the turtle, sometimes detects a collision even though it shouldn't!
MAIN:

import time
from turtle import Screen
from player import Player
from car_manager import CarManager
screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
player = Player()
cars = CarManager()
cars.hideturtle()
player.hideturtle()
game_is_on = True
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(fun=player.move, key="Up")

while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    scoreboard.display_score()
    screen.update()
    \# Creates cars from the left side of the screen
    cars.generate_cars()
    cars.move()
    \# To detect collision with cars
    for car in cars.car_list:
        if(car.distance(player)) \< 20:
        game_is_on = False
        screen.exitonclick()

# Player Class

from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITION = (0, -280)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
FINISH_LINE_Y = 280
class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player = Turtle()
        self.player.penup()
        self.player.shape("turtle")
        self.player.color("green")
        self.player.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)
        self.player.goto(0,-250)
        self.player.setheading(90)
    def move(self):
        self.player.forward(10)
    def check_y_pos(self):
        return self.player.ycor()

# Car Manager Class

from turtle import Turtle
import random

COLORS = \["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"\]
STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE = 5
MOVE_INCREMENT = 10

class CarManager(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.car_list = \[\]
    def generate_cars(self):
        random_chance = random.randint(1,6)
        if random_chance == 5:
            cars = Turtle()
            cars.penup()
            cars.shape("square")
            cars.goto(x=270, y=random.randint(a = -270, b = 270))
            cars.setheading(180)
            cars.shapesize(stretch_len=2, stretch_wid=1)
            cars.color(COLORS\[random.randint(0, 5)\])
            self.car_list.append(cars)
    def move(self):
        for car in self.car_list:
            car.forward(STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE)


Please remove escape characters from your code so the syntax is valid. For the purposes of the question, I'd just put all your code into one file. Avoid subclassing turtle, it leads to a ton of footguns, and avoid while loops. Any updates/sleeps should happen at the end of the update loop.

@ggorlen I believe the escape characters are inserted deliberately by the "question wizard" tool.

@JohnGordon that'd be a bug we should report on meta. I've never seen it, so I doubt this is the case. Probably, OP has taken some intermediate step instead of directly pasting the code into the question.

This is another case of confusion between inheritance and composition in turtle.
If you use Player(Turtle), then the Player is-a Turtle and inherits 100+ methods from Turtle.
If you use self.player = Turtle(), then Player has-a Turtle and those 100 turtle methods are namespaced in the self.player variable.
If you do both, then two turtles are created. If you call player.hideturtle(), that's still a hidden player turtle that can detect collisions. If you confuse method calls between player. and player.player, then bugs can arise.
In your code, you generally use the player.player turtle, except for collision detection:
if(car.distance(player)) < 20:

This reads nicely, but incorrectly uses the inherited, invisible turtle, not the composed turtle property you're using the rest of the time.
Change it to
if car.distance(player.player) < 20:

to minimally make your collision behave as expected (although technically, player should be private).
To avoid the problem entirely, never use inheritance with turtle. Always use composition. Instead of each entity being a turtle, think of your entities as having a turtle pen they can draw with. You can generally call it self.turtle or self.pen. This avoids a ton of footguns if you accidentally mix the two or confuse your subclass' methods with turtle methods.
Also, avoid while/sleep and call screen.update() at the end of your rendering loop. Never change positions outside of the rendering loop. Following these strategies will make the game feel smoother. See this post for details on realtime turtle--properly handling keypresses and the rendering loop.
Name variables clearly: if something is a list, make it plural, otherwise make it singular. So cars = [] and car = Turtle().
Putting these ideas into action, here's a potential rewrite:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice, randint


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.turtle = Turtle()
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.shape("turtle")
        self.turtle.color("green")
        self.turtle.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)
        self.turtle.goto(0, -250)
        self.turtle.setheading(90)

    def move(self):
        self.turtle.forward(5)

    def position(self):
        return self.turtle.position()


class CarManager:
    COLORS = "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"

    def __init__(self):
        self.cars = []

    def generate_car(self):
        if len(self.cars) > 40 or randint(0, 5):
            return

        car = Turtle()
        self.cars.append(car)
        car.penup()
        car.shape("square")
        car.goto(x=270, y=randint(a=-270, b=270))
        car.setheading(180)
        car.shapesize(stretch_len=2, stretch_wid=1)
        car.color(choice(CarManager.COLORS))

    def move_cars(self):
        for car in self.cars:
            car.forward(5)

            if car.xcor() < -270:
                car.goto(x=270, y=randint(a=-270, b=270))


def update():
    if "Up" in keys:
        player.move()

    car_manager.generate_car()
    car_manager.move_cars()

    for car in car_manager.cars:
        if car.distance(player.position()) < 30:
            screen.update()
            return

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(update, 1000 // 30)


screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
player = Player()
car_manager = CarManager()
keys = set()
screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(lambda: keys.add("Up"), key="Up")
screen.onkeyrelease(lambda: keys.remove("Up"), key="Up")
update()
screen.exitonclick()

There's still room for improvement, especially in playability and reducing the number of hardcoded variables.
Note that turtles are never garbage collected, so either use an object pool or respawn turtles that have moved off-screen, as shown above.
